# What happens if called program returns the exit code same as timeout command?

Tags: bash, shell, timeout, sh

I'm using **timeout** command in the Linux shell to call a program with a specific timeout.

And from the timeout command guide, it returns exit code 124 if a timeout happens, and returns the program exit code if no timeout happens.
Unfortunately, the program that I call also returns exit code 124 in some cases.

So I just want to ask if we have any way to recognize if 124 is from the timeout command or program?

code:

```
timeout 10s program 2>&1 | tee log.txt
if [ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" == 124 ]; then
    # do something
fi
```

Thanks

Comment: I suggest that you remove the _sh_ and the _bash_ tag. They seem to be unrelated to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do i.e. a

```
timeout --preserve-status 1 sleep 4
```

you would get a status of 143, which means that the command has been terminated by SIGTERM (128+15==143). Since a command is not supposed to return values larger than 127 to communicate a status condition, this could be used in your case to disambiguate between timeout and "real" exit status.

This assumes that you are using that `timeout` command which comes with the GNU coreutils.

Comment: Then how do we distinguish an actual SIGTERM from timeout?

Comment: Thanks @user1934428 , 127 is the key.

Comment: I just check the program that I call, it never returns a value greater than 127. And if I use --preserve-status option, and I receive the exit code 134, it can help me distinguish from 124.

Comment: @oguzismail : I guess it **is** an actual SIGTERM. Most likely, `timeout` uses SIGTERM to abort a long running programm. With signals, you never know who was sending the signal. This is not specific to timeouts.